# How to append an integer variable with hex literal number?

Tags: java, android

I have to use shift operator. I need to append a dynamically changing integer value with '0x'. How is it possible?
I have tried like below. But shows error

```
String json_value = object.getString("value");
int json_int = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
int final_int_value=0x+json_int;  //here shows error
System.out.println("SHIFT OPERATOR"+Integer.toBinaryString(final_int_value >> 2));
```

Comment: what error does it show ?

Comment: shows  - Invalid hex literal number

Comment: Do you want to convert an integer to hex value or viceversa?

Comment: 0x only works with integer literals.

Comment: if the value of json_int=03 , then final_int_value should be 0x03. Thats what I want

Comment: But an int cannot have 0x in it. 0x is specified to tell the compiler that it's a hex number. Even if you give, `int x = 0x03` it will store it as `x = 3` only. If you give `x = 0xff` it will store it as `x = 255`. Converting hex to int.

Comment: I understand that, but trying to append 0x+var_name is not valid. You can only use 0x with int literals. For example, 0x3456.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need this

```
int final_int_value=0x+json_int;  //here shows error
```

Simple you can achieve like this:

```
final String hex = "F";
final Integer intValue = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
System.out.println("SHIFT OPERATOR"+Integer.toHexString(intValue >> 2));
```

This will prints `3` as expected.

### Update

Additionally if you want to create hardcoded integer value from hex then you can define it with 0x

```
int myValue = 0xFF;
System.out.println("Hex:"+Integer.toHexString(myValue));
```

But you do not need to add any prefix (like 0x) to any integer programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.toBinaryString(json_int)

just like this